# basic function on char in c language

Tags: c, string, function, char

My prof instructed as to write an apology string using functions but I don't know how does it works and how I will define the sendApology function so here's my code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

void sendApology(char, int);

int main(void) {
    sendApology('s', 2);
    sendApology('f', 10);
    sendApology('b', 3);
    sendApology('o', 5);
    sendApology('r', 12);
    sendApology('m', 5);
    sendApology('v', 2);
    sendApology('y', 7);

    return 0;
}

void sendApology(char letter, int n) {

  // TODO: Implement the function definition

}
```

The instruction says: "The sendApology() function will first check if the character passed is either 's', 'o', 'r', or 'y'. If it is, print it based on the passed integer number of times. For example, if the passed integer is 5, then you need to print the character 5 times. Otherwise, just ignore it (i.e. don't do anything)." but I couldn't comprehend it well, appreciate for your help thaankss

Comment: It looks to me like `sendApology('s', 2);` should print `ss`, and `sendApology('f', 10);` should print nothing.  Not a terribly useful function in practice, but it shouldn't be too hard to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you need is just putc()
Put it in a loop on the count, and test if your character matches before using a loop on the range of accepted character.

Answer (score 3):

In simple terms, the instruction is saying:

1. Check if the variable `letter` is 's', 'o', 'r', or 'y'.
2. If it is one of these characters, print `letter` `n` times where n is the argument `n`
3. If it is not, do nothing

Some scenarios:

```
    sendApology('s', 2); // "ss"
    sendApology('f', 10); // nothing
    sendApology('b', 3); // nothing
    sendApology('o', 5); // "ooooo"
    sendApology('r', 12); // "rrrrrrrrrrrr"
    sendApology('m', 5); // nothing
    sendApology('v', 2); // nothing
    sendApology('y', 7); // "yyyyyyy"
```

Comment: Do you also intend to help according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ? In that case I will let you have a clear field and good luck.

Comment: @Yunnosch I didn't see this thread, but my post explains the asker's instructions which he's asked for. so I believe my reply is alright.

Comment: Yes, fair point. But pessimistic me predicts some follow up comments asking for details, code examples and help with upcoming errors. Because of "how I will define the sendApology function " and because of describing the skeleton/frame code probably given by teacher as "my code". Strictly speaking you did answer the question as asked, not blaming you.

Comment: yeah I get it but the question is how do I define the sendApology function?

Comment: @blewwwuuu I'm pretty sure you've already defined it by writing `void sendApology(char letter, int n) {}` You just need to put the logic in that function. If you're asking me for answers, I'm afraid it is against whatever Yunnosch has sent, as it is not in your best interest. If you're struggling I highly recommend you to contact your professor.

Comment: yeah sure thanks a lot though

Comment: @blewwwuuu If you want to ask "How to implement that function?" feel free to do so by using the "Ask Question" button. I am with danky, that their post answers your question as asked here. Keep it like it is, ask a new question, ideally according to [ask] and/or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and I will try to help you with it.